# CodeIgniter version 3.1.11 - How to post csv file in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv-import

I am new at codeigniter, i want to post csv file using this input method **$this->input->post()**.
I am using fopen() funtion of php for read csv file, it required file name and path in parameter.

this is my html simple html file.

```html
<form method="post" class="form" action="<?php echo base_url('csv/store'); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="myfile">Select a file:</label>
    <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile" accept=".csv">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

and this is my controller

```html
public function store() {
        $x = $this->input->post('myfile');
        $y = $this->input->post('name');
        print_r($x);
        print_r($y);
        exit;      
}
```

if i print $x it not getting output but if i print $y it is getting output.

Comment: Please use $_FILES instead of $x

Answer (score -1, accepted):

csv is a file...
so, use print_r($_FILES);

Comment: Thank you very much @Ganpat Thakor, it worked for me. Once i sure with the answer. I will up vote this answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you want to read an uploaded CSV file on your server with CI3.

In your Controller method store(), do the following -

1. You need to grab the uploaded file from the server. CI3 has a library "[upload](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html?highlight=upload)", use it.
2. Use fgetcsv() and fopen() to read the data.

Code

```
public function store() {
        $fileName = $this->input->post('name');
        $uploadPath = "./upload/csv/";
        
        // Config the upload
        config['upload_path'] = $uploadPath; // some directory on the server with write permission
        
        // CHecking if present else create one
        if (!file_exists($config['upload_path'])) {
            if (!mkdir($concurrentDirectory = $config['upload_path'], 0777,
                    true) && !is_dir($concurrentDirectory)) {
                throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Directory "%s" was not created', $concurrentDirectory));
            }
        }
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
        $config['max_size'] = '51200'; //50 MB
        $config['encrypt_name'] = false;
        $config['file_ext_tolower'] = true;
        
        // Set file name
        $config['file_name'] = $fileName;

        // Load the library with config
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        
        // Do the upload
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('paper')){
            // On error
            die($this->upload->display_errors());
        }else{
            // Upload was success, File is present in "./upload/csv/" 
            $csvFile = $uploadPath . $uploadData['file_name'];
            
            // Read the CSV file
            $row = 1;
            // Open the file and adjust the code as per your need
            if (($handle = fopen($csvFile, "r")) !== FALSE) {
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                    $num = count($data);
                    echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
                    $row++;
                    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                        echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
                    }
                }
                fclose($handle);
            }
        }
}
```

Point to member: Name your variable, method, function, constant in human readable form.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response @mail2bapi. All i want is after choose csv file if click on submit button, the data inside of csv file should be insert in my database table  **( my insert query is ready )**  but the condition is the csv file should not upload in my **local storage**.  Will above code satisfy my condition ?

Comment: I don't think you can do that without storing the uploading the file. One thing you can do is to delete the file after data extraction